# Choose where to save a file during runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a text file with some text by clicking a button. After I click the button, I want to choose where to save the file. How can I do this?

I'm using C# windows application forms.

I tried using the code below, but it requires me to provide the path in the code. What I want is to choose the path during runtime.

```
FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("D:\\file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);
writer.Write("Hello");
writer.Close();
```

Comment: Yes. I need to create txt file

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Nobody is going to write code for you.

Comment: Do you want to design a new notepad application, or do you want to use a notepad application that already exists?

Comment: Why do you need to open it in Notepad first? Can you just create it? Does it need to be notepad or 'default" text editor is ok?

Comment: FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("D:\\file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);
            writer.Write("Hello");
            writer.Close();  But here I need to give a path. I need to create txt filr with out giving a path.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to type some text, click a button, then the program will ask you where to save the text file?

Comment: No. Click button --> open a txt file with my text --> save file manually

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Click a button, Open an **existing** text file, and Save it to somewhere else? Or: Click a button, Create a new file and Save it somewhere?

Comment: Click a button --> open new txt file with my text --> save it a place where I want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After getting some clarification in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532153#comment36099978_23532153), it seems that you're looking for the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It will allow you to select a location to save the file.

This is some (slightly modified) sample code from the MSDN reference above:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ; // or just "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt" if you only want to save text files
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

    if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
        {
            // Insert your code to write the stream here.
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here how can I give my text to the txt file?

Comment: You could use a `StreamWriter` as you've already done in your code. Use `new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName)` to open the file and write into it.